# How to declare a Worksheet using a Script Task?

Tags: c#, excel, ssis, etl, script-task

I'm trying to declare a Worksheet to handle cells of .xlsx file, but my C# script fails when I declare Worksheet object :

```
Microsoft.Office.Interop.Excel.Application xlApp = new 
Microsoft.Office.Interop.Excel.Application();

Workbook excelBook = xlApp.Workbooks.Open(fileFullPath);

MySheet = (Excel.Worksheet)excelBook.Worksheets[Data_Sheet];
```

I've tried all of this statements :

```
MySheet workSheet = (Worksheet)excelBook.Application.Sheets[1];  
MySheet = (Excel.Worksheet)excelBook.Worksheets[1];
```

Even

```
Worksheet MySheet = new Worksheet();
MySheet = excelBook.Worksheets[Data_Sheet];
```

I'm using this code in a script task in SSIS package and it doesn't show me the error message, I have only the error window telling me that the contained scripts have error compilation.

Thank you for your help.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

*I really didn't understood if you are looking to add a new worksheet or just edit a current one. I will give some suggestions for both cases:*

## (1) Edit an existing Worksheet

*If you are looking to edit an existing Worksheet, try one of the following:*

### (a) Using _Worksheet instead of Worksheet

```
Excel._Worksheet xlWorksheet = (Excel._Worksheet)xlWorkbook.Sheets[1];
```

As example:

```
Excel.Application xlApp = new Excel.Application();
Excel.Workbook xlWorkbook = xlApp.Workbooks.Open(@"file.xlsx");
Excel._Worksheet xlWorksheet = xlWorkbook.Sheets[1];
Excel.Range xlRange = xlWorksheet.UsedRange;
```

*For more information, check to following links:*

- [Read Excel File in C#](https://coderwall.com/p/app3ya/read-excel-file-in-c)
- [Reading data from excel 2010 using Microsoft.Office.Interop.Excel](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/15873389/reading-data-from-excel-2010-using-microsoft-office-interop-excel)
- [Excel interop: _Worksheet or Worksheet?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1051464/excel-interop-worksheet-or-worksheet)

### (b) Interop Library Version

Check that the Office.Interop DLL you are using are relevant to the officeversion installed on the machine.

### (c) Permissions and Protection issues

Check that the workbook is not ReadOnly or it is protected, you can refer to the following SO question:

- [Excel interop prevent showing password dialog](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/44168594/excel-interop-prevent-showing-password-dialog)

### (d) Hidden Worksheets issue

Also make sure that the workbook does not contains hidden or temp worksheets, try to loop over all Worksheets in the Workbook and Debug the code to see what is going on.

---

## (2) Add a new Worksheet

*If you are looking to add a new worksheet to an existing workbook you can:*

### (a) Add it via Script-Task

You can use a similar code:

```
Excel._Worksheet newWorksheet;
newWorksheet = (Excel._Worksheet)ThisWorkbook.Worksheets.Add();
```

*For more information, you can check the following links:*

- [How to: Programmatically add new worksheets to workbooks](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/visualstudio/vsto/how-to-programmatically-add-new-worksheets-to-workbooks?view=vs-2017)
- [How to create a new worksheet in Excel file c#?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/16705651/how-to-create-a-new-worksheet-in-excel-file-c)

### (b) Use Execute SQL Task

First you have to create an `Excel Connection Manager`, then add an Execute SQL Task, choose the Excel Connection and write a `CREATE` Statement, as example:

```
CREATE TABLE
`Excel Destination` (

    `PromotionKey` INTEGER,
    `PromotionAlternateKey` INTEGER,
    `EnglishPromotionName` NVARCHAR(255),
    `SpanishPromotionName` NVARCHAR(255),
    `FrenchPromotionName` NVARCHAR(255),
    `DiscountPct` DOUBLE PRECISION,
    `EnglishPromotionType` NVARCHAR(50),
    `SpanishPromotionType` NVARCHAR(50),
    `FrenchPromotionType` NVARCHAR(50),
    `EnglishPromotionCategory` NVARCHAR(50),
    `SpanishPromotionCategory` NVARCHAR(50),
    `FrenchPromotionCategory` NVARCHAR(50),
    `StartDate` DATETIME,
    `EndDate` DATETIME,
    `MinQty` INTEGER,
    `MaxQty` INTEGER

)
```

*For more information, you can check the following links:*

- [SSIS: Dynamically Generate Excel Table/Sheet](https://dwhanalytics.wordpress.com/2011/04/07/ssis-dynamically-generate-excel-tablesheet/)

Comment: Thank you for your precious answers. Actually, I'm trying to edit an existing worksheet, after looking and trying all the declarations I've found this one in one of the links above and it's the only one that works for me : `Worksheet xlSheets = excelBook.Sheets[1] as Excel.Worksheet;` and I don't know whey and I've checked all the points that you mentioned : DLL : Assembly Microsoft.Office.Interop.Excel
C:\Windows\assembly\GAC_MSIL\Microsoft.Office.Interop.Excel\15.0.0.0__71e9bce111e9429c\Microsoft.Office.Interop.Excel.dll, the workbook is not ReadOnly.

Comment: But I'm still having issue with range and cells. I'm trying to use : `Range rng = xlSheets.Cells[RowIndex, ColumnIndex] as Excel.Range;
rng.Font.Color = System.Drawing.ColorTranslator.ToOle(System.Drawing.Color.Red);` but this generates exception without compilation error. Can you help me with please ?

Comment: actually it works when I'm replacing `Cells[RowIndex, ColumnIndex]` by `Cells[1, 1]`. But I need to get indexes from variables that I handle before in the script :         `int RowIndex = 0;
int ColumnIndex = 0;                                                                                                         ColumnIndex = ColumnData.Table.Columns[ColumnDataCellsValue].Ordinal;         RowIndex = dtDataRows.Rows.IndexOf(rowDataID);`. Thank you for your help

Comment: the cell row and column index are not zero based, so you cannot start with `0`, you have to start looping from `1` -> `int RowIndex = 1; int ColumnIndex = 1; ColumnIndex = ColumnData.Table.Columns[ColumnDataCellsValue].Ordinal + 1; RowIndex = dtDataRows.Rows.IndexOf(rowDataID) + 1;`

Comment: I could not try this before today and it works like a charm. I'm really very thankful for your precious help and clear answers.

Answer (score 1):

The Office Interop / Object Model API is based on running Office code in the context of your application.  It expects to be running on the UI thread of an interactive (i.e. non-server) application.

See **[Considerations for server-side Automation of Office](https://support.microsoft.com/en-us/help/257757/considerations-for-server-side-automation-of-office)**

If you ever do get this working, it will fail at just about the most inconvenient time.

If you need to manipulate Office documents on a server, use a server-side appropriate API like OpenXML

Comment: thanks for your answer, actually my need is to change color of a cell based on RowIndex and ColumnIndex that's why I'm using Office Interop. The rest of the scripts works fine I can get column value correctly but when trying to highlight the cell of dataset a person recommended me to use Office Interop because according to what he said it's not possible to change color of cell from dataset : 'object CellToHigh = dsDataCell.Tables[Data_Sheet].Rows[RowIndex][ColumnIndex];' There is any other solution without using OpenXML ? because it looks complicated to me to use this solution.

Comment: No good ever comes from running Excel on a server.  I used to work in Microsoft support, and that KB article was probably the one that I sent customers the most often.

Comment: My issue will be solved by installing Open XML SDK 2.5 ? and adding DocumentFormat.OPENXML to references ? is this the solution please  or I have ? And FYI I use Office Interop in a previous scripttask in the same package to retrieve spreadsheet name and it works well.

Comment: All I'm saying is that using Office interop on a server may or may not work.  It may work for a while and then fail inexplicably.  Microsoft doesn't support it, and any advice you get about making this work is likely wrong.  Yeah, the OpenXML SDK is a very big stick (but, if you go that route, make sure to download the OpenXML Productivity Tool and get used to what it can do for you).  There are also other Office file APIs (though I can't think of their names - dig around stack overflow, looking at the `[Excel]` tag

Comment: Otherwise, can you give me please an alternative solution to server-side Automation it's not clear on Microsoft page.