# Is it Possible to create drop down columns in Excel sheet using SSIS Script task with C# Language?

Tags: c#, excel, ssis, script-task

I am trying to create drop down columns in already existed Excel Sheet using Script task. I know that we can do it using C# but not sure is it possible in SSIS Script task. If it is possible please guide me.

I am new to SSIS technology.

Answer (score 0):

Yes you can do it in Script task since it is a C# project where you can use external assemblies such as `Interop.Excel.dll`

Example:

- [How to declare a Worksheet using a Script Task?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/54482379/how-to-declare-a-worksheet-using-a-script-task/54483952#54483952)